# Should I rebase with dev branch before making a pull request?

Tags: git, rebase, pull-request

Our current workflow:

create a feature branch from dev.
after developing the feature and having pushed the branch
do a the following:

`git checkout dev`

`git pull --rebase` (on dev)

`git checkout my-feature-branch`

`git rebase dev`

resolve conflicts and then do a git push -f or git push (first time).

My question comes from one of our development team members:

**Do we need to do the whole process as is, or can we just make the pull-request directly, especially that the response is always "I am working on a component which is not shared by any other developer" ?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a workflow question: and the best workflow will always be opinion based. They all have tradeoffs. Do what you decide on as a team, and stick with it. Understand the pros and cons of what you're doing. All workflows have their ups and downs.

Answer (score 45):

Let's say, while you are working on your `feature-branch`, new stuff is integrated onto the `dev` branch. So the history might look like this:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 5 (dev)
    \
     4 - 6 - 7 - 8 (feature-branch)
```

If you simply create a pull-request and the `dev` branch maintainer would have to merge it, he would need to deal with potential conflicts -- bad for the `dev` branch maintainer.

If you rebase the `feature-branch` branch onto `dev` and resolve potential conflicts before submitting the pull-request,

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 5 (dev)
             \
              4 - 6 - 7 - 8 (feature-branch)
```

it will be just a quick and easy fast-forward merge for the `dev` branch maintainer.

This workflow enforces developers to resolve conflicts locally and makes the live of the integrator easier.

Comment: Perfect answer thank you, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you all.

Comment: would force push needed if suppose commit 7 already exists on remote branch (till 7 rebase was not done or dev was not committed with 3 & 4) ?

Comment: What are the git commands to do what you just explained?

Comment: @Pawel On the `feature-branch`, `git rebase dev`.

Answer (score 4):

Your workflow is just the typical rebase workflow I would expect to see being used to keep a feature branch directly ahead of its ancestor, which in this case is the `dev` branch.  If you want to leave open the possibility of the `my-feature-branch` fast-forwarding the `dev` branch during the pull request, then yes, you need to do all these steps.  Note that the force push might be required because the rebase on `dev` can rewrite the history of the feature branch.

As to whether you should be doing a rebase workflow versus a merge or other workflow, this is subjective and depends on many things.  But, if rebase does make the most sense, then I agree with your current steps and don't see a way to simplify it.